# About:blank on tablet ( iPad )

Tags: html, ipad, hyperlink

**Problem**
Since this week I'm testing a clients affiliate website ( http://www.fashioncheque-online.nl ) on responsibility. I recognized something that I never saw before. When you click on a link on your desktop ( for instance http://www.fashioncheque-online.nl/overzicht/webshops/dames/schoenen/ and click on Shoeby for example ) then you see that the link will open correctly in a new tab. But when I click on the same link on my iPad I only get to see about:blank. It should be loading an affiliate link, but it seems like it doesn't load the page further. When I click on another tab over the browser, then the browser loads the affiliate page further.

**Question**
Now is my question, does anybody got a solution for this problem? Is it maybe the browser ( Safari ) or is it the way I build up my links?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have a hint of a solution, but I might be totally wrong.
Your code structure for the links is a follow :

```
<li style="display: inline-block;">
    <a href="LINK" onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','LINK']);" rel="external">
        <h4>Shoeby</h4>
        <div class="product-image">
            <img src="IMG" alt="" scale="0">
        </div>
        <div class="productmoreholder">
            <div class="productmoretag">LINK</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

I think that iOS devices don't take into account the onclick="javascript" the same way as laptops and desktop computers. Why don't you simply add a `target="_blank"` (even though it would become redundant on desktops) ?

I hope this helped !

Cheers

//quentindelattre

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks for your reaction! I found a solution for this problem! :)

This is the solution for this problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('a[rel="external"]').click(function() {
     window.open( $(this).attr('href') );
     return false;
  });
</script>
```

The HTML for the link must be:

```
<a href="http://google.com" rel="external">
```